# Execute function after return

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodejs with expressjs for my api.

I want to call a function after res.json() is called.

for example the api fetches data to the client but i want to log that action but no need to make client wait for request response till the api saves log

```
module.exports = {
  getAll:async function(req,res){
    ////fetch data from db
    res.json({success:true,data:data});
    module.exports.logthis();
    return;
  },
  logthis: async function ()
  {
    //save log
  }
}
```

is this true that logthis will not be interupted after return; is called ?
also is there a better pattern to do this, like a event queue listener so that i threw that request in a pool and it's executed whenever it's possible ?

Comment: Are you looking for [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)?

Comment: @raina77ow no i don't want to await logthis, i want the function to return as soon as res.json is called, cuz client doesn't have to wait for log to be saved.

Comment: `I want to call a function after res.json() is called` - what does 'after' mean in this case? Do you want to call `logthis` after `json()` has returned? Use `await`. Do you want to call `logthis` immediately after? Do it before even calling `json()`. Want something else? Clarify.

Comment: @raina77ow i don't want the client to keep waiting for request response until logthis is done, so i can't use await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a json response to the client or using `return` statement will not stop the script from executing `logthis` function only if you put `return` statement before it.

```
module.exports = {

    getAll:async function(req,res){

        //fetch data from db

        res.json({success:true,data:data});

        this.logthis(data);

        return;
    },

    logthis: function (data) {
        // log data to file here
    }

}
```

Remember that `async` function works in conjunction with `await` statement, if you don't have asynchronous functions inside `getAll` there is no need to use `async` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use callback or promise instead.
function (data, callback){
    DB.find(........)
     callback(err,data)
      // Do other stuff here.

}

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
res.json({success:true,data:data}).then(function(){
  //Enter your code here. res.json() has finished.
});
```